# Constexpr Errors

Tags: c++, templates

Okay I fixed the errors. Thank you guys. But now when I run it, I choose D in the menu but only "You chose to split the words & remove the duplicates in the paragraph" & "This is it:" prints out. It doesn't show anything after that ... Anyone know what it could be? Thank you in advance!!

This is how it should be:

When the 4th choice (“Split Words”) is selected, the words should be put into an array or a structure of your and each word should be displayed with a loop. After this duplicate removal should be performed and the program must determine the duplicate words and eliminate them. After this, the word list should be printed again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string s;
    char selection;
    string w;
    string buf;


    cout << "Enter a paragraph or a sentence : " ;

    getline(cin, s);

    int sizeOfString = s.length(); 

    //cout << "The paragraph has " << sizeOfString << " characters. " << endl; ***Dummy call to see if size works. 

    //cout << "You entered " << s << endl; *** Dummy function !!

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "                 Menu          " << endl;
    cout <<"        ------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "A -- Convert paragraph to all caps " << endl;
    cout << "B -- Convert paragraph to all lowercase " << endl;
    cout << "C -- Delete whitespaces " << endl;
    cout << "D -- Split words & remove duplicates " << endl;
    cout << "E -- Search a certain word " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please select one of the above: " ;
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "" << endl;

    stringstream ss(s); 
    set<string> tokens;

    switch (selection) //Switch statement
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "You chose to convert the paragraph to all uppercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
                    {
                        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
                    }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                  break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B': cout << "You chose to convert the paragragh to all lowercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for (int i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
                  {
                      s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
                  }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C': cout << "You chose to delete the whitespaces in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                    if(s[i] == ' ') s.erase(i,1);
                  cout <<"This is it: " << s << endl;
                  break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': cout << "You chose to split the words & remove the duplicates in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                 // Insert the string into a stream

                  // Create vector to hold our words

                  while (ss >> buf)
                    tokens.insert(buf);

                  cout << "This is it: " << endl;

                  for (set<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
                    {
                        cout << *it << " ";
                    }

        cout << endl;

        break;




        case 'e':
        case 'E': cout << "You chose to search for a certain word in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "Enter the word you want to search for: ";
                  cin >> w;

                  s.find(w);
                  if ( s.find( w ) != std::string::npos )
                  {
                      cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;

                  }
                 else 
                  {
                    cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  }




    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case D, in your for loop, you have `set<s>`. `s` is not a type. You meant to write string I think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Adding a more descriptive title will get better attention for this post.  Also, I'd try to minimize the code you post an as example.

Comment: `set<s>::iterator` should be `set<string>::iterator`

Comment: What compiler are you using? Doesn't it tell you at which line you are having the errors? I think many errors are all due to what Luke and Nathan said, but it would be nice if you indicated where they are.

Comment: Now we can't see how 'ss' is defined and used previously. Please add follow up questions at the end of your original post after an 'Edit:'. And make a nice formatting of it, makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
set<s>::iterator
```

should be

```
set<string>::iterator
```

2) Add brackets around the case statements for the local variables.

```
case 'D':{

}
break;

case 'e':

case 'E':{


}
break;
```

Comment: I don't like these brackets... they look so sad.

Comment: Local variables declared in one case are still visible below. But initialisation is jumped over by the switch going to a case below.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating stringstream with empty string, which, in turn leads to stream being empty. Consider creating stringstream object after you actually read the string. stringstream doesn't hold a reference to your string object, so any modification to a string the stringstream was based on, doesn't reflect those changes in the stream.